# Detect whether WPF resource exists, based on URI

Tags: wpf, resources, pack-uri

Given a pack:// URI, what's the best way to tell whether a compiled resource (e.g. a PNG image, compiled with a Build Action of "Resource") actually exists at that URI?

After some stumbling around, I came up with this code, which works but is clumsy:

```
private static bool CanLoadResource(Uri uri)
{
    try
    {
        Application.GetResourceStream(uri);
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

<s>(Note that the [Application.GetResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms596994.aspx) documentation [is wrong](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=523550) -- it throws an exception if the resource isn't found, rather than returning null like the docs incorrectly state.)</s> *(The docs have been corrected, see comments below)*

I don't like catching exceptions to detect an expected (non-exceptional) result. And besides, I don't actually want to load the stream, I just want to know whether it exists.

Is there a better way to do this, perhaps with lower-level resource APIs -- ideally without actually loading the stream and without catching an exception?

Comment: They updated the doc, it says there that it throws exception when resource not found.

Comment: @Shimmy, thanks for the update -- I've edited to include that info.

Comment: @John White: BTW, I think you should mark [jpierson's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013481/detect-whether-wpf-resource-exists-based-on-uri/2549641#2549641) as answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found a solution that I'm using which doesn't work directly with a pack Uri but instead looks up a resource by it's resource path. That being said, this example could be modified pretty easily to support a pack URI instead by just tacking on the resource path to the end of a uri which uses the Assembly to formulate the base part of the URI.

```
public static bool ResourceExists(string resourcePath)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    return ResourceExists(assembly, resourcePath);
}

public static bool ResourceExists(Assembly assembly, string resourcePath)
{
    return GetResourcePaths(assembly)
        .Contains(resourcePath.ToLowerInvariant());
}

public static IEnumerable<object> GetResourcePaths(Assembly assembly)
{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var resourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g";
    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceName, assembly);

    try
    {
        var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);

        foreach(System.Collections.DictionaryEntry resource in resourceSet)
        {
            yield return resource.Key;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        resourceManager.ReleaseAllResources();
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the returned paths from `GetResourcePaths` is lowercased so make sure to use `.Contains(resourcePath.ToLower());` in the `ResourceExists` method.

Comment: Make that `.ToLowerInvariant()` just to be safe.

Comment: Would be nice to see a general solution that searched through all loaded assemblies (maybe making an educated first-guess by parsing assemblyname from the "pack:" string.)

Comment: This is the only real answer to finding if a resource exists, that you compile into an assembly using Build Action > Resource.  All other GetResourceName solutions do NOT work.  Thank you so much! @Jpierson