# WPF - check resource exists without structured exception handling

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, exception, embedded-resource

Is there any way to check if a resource exists in an assembly without having to use exception handling?  I'm currently loading images from several assemblies, and if they don't exist then I'm handling the IOException, which causes quite a bit of overhead.

Comment: This is the only working solution IMHO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013481/detect-whether-wpf-resource-exists-based-on-uri

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
// Member Variable
string [] resourceNames;

// Function
Boolean ResourceExists(string resourceName)
{
    if (resourceNames == null)
    {
        resourceNames =  
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames(); 
    }

    return resourceNames.Contains(resourceName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, we've ended up using a similar approach where we build a dictionary of resources contained in an assembly, then this dictionary is checked against when retrieving an image.

Answer (score 0):

Copied answer from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e2cb620-14c5-4996-9864-d43e6de5d665/how-to-test-if-a-wpf-resource-exists-from-its-pack-uri?forum=wpf):

```
public static bool ResourceExists(string resourcePath)
{
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    return ResourceExists(assembly, resourcePath);
}

public static bool ResourceExists(Assembly assembly, string resourcePath)
{
    return GetResourcePaths(assembly)
        .Contains(resourcePath);
}

public static IEnumerable<object> GetResourcePaths(Assembly assembly)
{
    var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    var resourceName = assembly.GetName().Name + ".g";
    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceName, assembly);

    try
    {
        var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);

        foreach(System.Collections.DictionaryEntry resource in resourceSet)
        {
            yield return resource.Key;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        resourceManager.ReleaseAllResources();
    }
}
```