# Searching/Listing WPF resource files?

Tags: wpf, resources, resource-files, resource-file

Is there a way to search a WPF application for resources?

I have added many images to an app and want to perform search i.e. `MS*.jpg` etc., Is this possible?

If I could create a list of all the resources, that would surely be helpful as well, but I don't want it to cost to much performance (I will make it lazy loaded tho).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have them all under an `IEnumerable<string>` the search job is hell of a lot easier.

```
public static IEnumerable<object> GetResourcePaths()
{
  var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
  var resourceName = CurrentAssembly.GetName().Name + ".g";
  var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceName, CurrentAssembly);

  try
  {
    var resourceSet = resourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, true);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resourceSet)
    {
      yield return resource.Key;
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    resourceManager.ReleaseAllResources();
  }
}
```

Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2013481/detect-whether-wpf-resource-exists-based-on-uri/2549641#2549641)